# Constructing equilateral triangles on the sides of a right angled triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Let $ABC$ be a right triangle right angled at $C$. Three equilateral triangles $BCP,ACQ,ABR$ such that $P-A,Q-B,R-C$ are points on the opposite sides of $BC,AC,AB$. Prove that $AP=BQ=CR$

[image]

I proved this by plotting all the points on a cartesian plane and finding the distances manually. However, Im sure that a much simpler geometric solution exists. I played around with some theorems but unfortunately, none of them helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\triangle ACP \cong \triangle QCB~$ and so $AP = BQ$

$\triangle RBC \cong \triangle ABP~$ and so $CR = AP$

Comment: It was that simple!

Comment: You will find a similar 1826 proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem)